# Build Apple Silicon binary on Intel machine

Tags: c, macos, arm, autotools, apple-silicon

How can I compile a C project on macOS 11 (Intel) to work on Silicon?

My current build script is as simple as:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I've tried using the `--host` and `--target` flags with `aarch64-apple-darwin` and `arm-apple-darwin` without any luck.

The binary always defaults to `x86_64`:

```
> file foobar.so
foobar.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems cc and gcc aren't found when `--host` is specified.

```
checking for arm-apple-darwin-cc... no
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... no
```

Comment: You got latest XCode 12 installed?  You'll need that at a minimum.

Comment: @selbie: This runs on GitHub actions and the Xcode version is 12.2.

Comment: See my answer below. You likely want `-target arm64-apple-macos11` . Notice that the target parameter is preceded with a single dash, and not double dashes.

Comment: Did you get it to compile for arm ?

Comment: No, we ended up renting a MacStadium M1 machine, but still need to compile this on x84 for arm ‍♂️

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We ended up solving solving this and being able to compile `darwin-arm64` and `debian-aarch64` binaries on GitHub Actions' x86-64 machines.

We pre-compiled all our dependencies for arm64 and linked them statically as well as dynamically.

```bash
export RELAY_DEPS_PATH=./build-deps/arm64
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=./build-deps/arm64/lib/pkgconfig

cd ./relay-deps
TARGET=./build-deps make install

cd ./relay
phpize
./configure CFLAGS='-target arm64-apple-macos' \
  --host=aarch64-apple-darwin \
  --enable-relay-jemalloc-prefix
  [snip...]

make

# Dynamically linked binary
cc --target=arm64-apple-darwin \
  ${wl}-flat_namespace ${wl}-undefined ${wl}suppress \
  -o .libs/relay.so -bundle .libs/*.o \
  -L$RELAY_DEPS_PATH/lib -lhiredis -ljemalloc_pic [snip...]

# re-link to standard paths
./relay-deps/utils/macos/relink.sh .libs/relay.so /usr/local/lib
cp .libs/relay.so modules/relay.so

# Build a statically linked shared object
cc --target=arm64-apple-darwin \
  ${wl}-flat_namespace ${wl}-undefined ${wl}suppress \
  -o .libs/relay-static.so -bundle .libs/*.o \
  $RELAY_DEPS_PATH/lib/libhiredis.a \
  $RELAY_DEPS_PATH/lib/libjemalloc_pic.a \
  [snip...]
```

The `relink.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

printUsage() {
    echo "$0 <shared-object> <prefix>"
    exit 1
}

if [[ ! -f "$1" || -z "$2" ]]; then
    printUsage
    exit 1
fi

INFILE=$1
PREFIX=$2

links=(libjemalloc libhiredis [snip...])

if [ -z "$PREFIX" ]; then
    PREFIX=libs
fi

for link in ${links[@]}; do
    FROM=$(otool -L "$INFILE"|grep $link|awk '{print $1}')
    FILE=$(basename -- "$FROM")
    TO="$PREFIX/$FILE"

    echo "$FROM -> $TO"
    install_name_tool -change "$FROM" "$TO" "$1"
done
```

Answer (score 15):

I found a hint on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/building_a_universal_macos_binary) to use this:

```
-target arm64-apple-macos11
```

When I run this from my mac:

```
clang++ main.cpp -target arm64-apple-macos11
```

The resulting a.out binary is listed as:

```
% file a.out
a.out: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

I have XCode 12.2 installed.

I don't have an Arm Mac in front of me, so I'm assuming this works.

Comment: How can I specify `clang++` as the compiler when using `./configure`?

Comment: You probably don't have to.  Clang is the default compiler and `g++` command line is really just a shim that forwards to clang.

Comment: Unfortunately we have to use ./configure, since we have several flags. Is there any way to tell `./configure` to use `clang++`?

Comment: I'm not an expert on autoconf (which is the tool that genrates configure scripts). 
 But you probably just need to have the script set `CC=clang` and `CXX=clang++`

Comment: We tried that without any luck. Autotools ‍♂️

Comment: I get `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture` type errors when I try this.

Comment: @AlecJacobson - are you on the latest version of XCode?  And have installed all the latest command line tools?

Comment: Yes, I have the latest. It's now working if I use `clang++ main.cpp -target arm64-apple-macos11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk`

Answer (score 4):

Mr. Curious was curious about cross-compilation to M1 as well. One unexpected solution is [Zig](https://ziglang.org). It aims to be the best way to cross-compile C, among other things; it easily targets M1 from Linux.

There was a series of streams about cross compiling to M1 a couple of weeks ago: [Part 1](https://vimeo.com/519725401) shows how to use Zig as a cross-compiler in existing makefiles, and in [Part 3](https://vimeo.com/524007646) they successfully demonstrate compiling Redis on Linux for M1.

Highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, I'll dig into Zig this afternoon!